# What are the largest LEGO® Power train sets available commercially [Oct 2014]

Tags: sets, trains, power-functions

What set(s) are the largest by number of pieces? These sets could be retired or existing.

I am also curious what set(s) have the most rails pieces included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now, the largest commercially available train is the [Lego City Cargo Train, Set 60052](http://brickset.com/sets/60052-1/Cargo-Train). It comes in at about 887 pieces. There are 30 rail pieces in this kit. Extra rail pieces are also commercially available through Lego. The [7898-1 cargo train](http://brickset.com/sets/7898-1/Cargo-Train-Deluxe) would come in second as far as piece count. Same amount of track as the 60052.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from those mentioned by Joe, there are several larger sets in the Advanced Models category. They are not powered out of the box, but can be motorized.

These are:

- [10233-1: Horizon Express](http://brickset.com/sets/10233-1/Horizon-Express) 1351 pieces
- [10219: Maersk Train](http://brickset.com/sets/10219-1/Maersk-Train) 1237 pcs
- [10194: Emerald Night](http://brickset.com/sets/10194-1/Emerald-Night) 1085 pcs
- [10183: Hobby Trains](http://brickset.com/sets/10183-1/Hobby-Trains) 1080 pcs (This is actually for the previous train system, that used electrically conductive rails on 9V - so it is simultaneously powered and incompatible with the new, all-plastic rails)

Also, if you need more rails, check out the dedicated rail packages:

- [8867-1: Flexible Train Tracks](http://brickset.com/sets/8867-1/Flexible-Train-Tracks)
- [7499-1: Flexible and Straight Tracks](http://brickset.com/sets/7499-1/Flexible-and-Straight-Tracks)
- [7896-1: Straight and Curved Rails](http://brickset.com/sets/7896-1/Straight-and-Curved-Rails)